# Trouble to read a File with paths and check if them exist

Tags: shell, unix

I'm trying to check if some paths exist or not. The paths are in a text file

This is the text file:

```
/cygdrive/c/scriptstest/test1

/cygdrive/c/scriptstest/test2

/cygdrive/c/scriptstest/test3

/cygdrive/c/scriptstest/test4
```

The paths `test1`, `test2`, `test3` exist.

My code is

```
while read -r line;
do
    echo $line
    if [ -d $line ];  then
        echo "Exist"
    else
        echo  "No exist"
    fi
done < test2.txt
```

And here is the problem:

```
/cygdrive/c/scriptstest/test1
No exist

/cygdrive/c/scriptstest/test2
No exist

/cygdrive/c/scriptstest/test3
No exist

/cygdrive/c/scriptstest/test4
No exist
```

The results are always negative, but when I copy and paste the paths direct into code, the results are OK:

```
#if [ -d "/cygdrive/c/scriptstest/test1" ]; --> using the path direct in the code
output
/cygdrive/c/scriptstest/test1
Exist
```

Why is this not working in the script?

Comment: did you try to put quotes around line like this? `if [ -d "$line" ]` I tried your code on my computer and it worked.

Comment: are you making sure to run the code in the correct directory? you know `-d` checks if it is a directory, and not if it is a file? (use `-f` for that)

Comment: Yes I have try use quotes. You didn't modify anything else? Yes I'm usinbg -d, I need check if the folders exist or not. Thanks

Comment: I didn't modify anything, only copy/pasted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the `paths.txt` file.  It had been saved with DOS line endings  - so I was actually testing for a directory name ending with a carriage return.  That wasn't obvious when printing (and would have been more obvious with `printf '%q\n' "$line"` instead of `echo $line`).

Removing the carriage returns from the line ends fixed the problem.

Comment: glad you found out what was wrong. You should accept your own answer :)